# Express static files not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm doing a simple node project to practice but i can't manage to serve html file with its css styles.

I believe that it worked fine for me before with the same code but now I don't understand why it doesn't run.
I searched about it and copied some code replacing the directory's name but it doesn't change anything.
Here is my code.
I also tried with path module to join the file name and the directory name.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
res.send("Welcome to our website");
});
app.get("/signup", (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

//My directory:

 testapp1
    --node_modules
    --public
      --styles.css
    --index.html
    --app.js
    --package.json
    --package-lock.json
```

In the network tab of the developer console, it says that:
   status: canceled
   type: stylesheet
   initiator: index.html
   Size: 0B
   time: 29ms
   waterfall: "nothing"

Comment: are you seeing 'welcome to our website' when you access the top level url?

Comment: open developer console, network tab and check the responses when the style is requested, what does the server say? Really need more info to debug this.

Comment: Yes i see "welcome to our website" when access the top level url. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

Try that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work it shows: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Med\Desktop\testApp1\index.html' even when i moved the index.html file to public directory

Comment: so if the issue (sorry just reread the question) is for the CSS files, you can just provide a link in index.html with a path direction

Comment: Thank you, the solution was so simple: I was missing a point in the link of css file

Comment: its too easy to make little typos etc. that lead to hours of frustration, glad to help